# Removing a board that’s adhered onto heat sink

Tags: rework

I am working on a rework project that requires I get to the back side of the board to inspect the flash and also SDRAM. The issue I’m having is they have the board glued to the heat sink and also encased leaving you little to no room for error.
I am curious if there’s any advice or some tips or tricks on getting this board out to work on it.
Any advice is much appreciated.
[image: sorry for the crappy picture had to find one online]

[image: here’s a closer look, if you look on the right edge you can see adhesive]

Comment: If you can show a few photos...

Comment: Heat gun or solvent, depending on the adhesive material.  Do you know what it is?  Probable some type of heat conduction film, like Aptek or Able Film.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what it is. It’s gray in color and from what I understand it’s not easy to remove

Comment: Pry gently while applying heat, or pry gently while soaking in solvent I'd say. You might also consider destructively modifying the case or heatsink to get better access.

Comment: Under the hood automotive application, like an ECU?

Comment: If it's thermal epoxy, you're pretty much limited to machining it off...

Comment: I additionally see transparent conformal coating on the PCB itself, so even after removing the thermal adhesive, whatever it is, you still have another layer to go through